# Building help dialog with wxPython

Tags: wxpython

I have been keen on building a dialog with which to store and present the help documentation for my wxPython application. Currently, the help documentation is stored as plain text files with minimal formatting. I can foresee a direct import of the documentation into a notebook class or something similar. I am hoping someone can direct me at what I should be looking at for building something similar to this:[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have used HTMLWindow for displaying some nicely formatted text. It only accepts basic HTML constructs, but it's enough for this sort of thing. I have an example [here](http://www.blog.pythonlibrary.org/2008/06/11/wxpython-creating-an-about-box/). Otherwise, you can probably use one of the TextCtrl widgets in read-only mode. There are lots of examples in the wxPython demo that you can look at for those widgets.